# Bind List of objects to datagridview with Fluent NHibernate - ToString override

Tags: c#, nhibernate, data-binding, datagridview, fluent-nhibernate

I have problem with displaying List of my objects like datasource in datagridview. I have class with few properties. Two of them are another objects.

I've tried to override ToString() in my classes, but i'm getting an exceptions, witch tells, than cell for my object has int32 type ( i think, is an ID of my object)

Withount tostring override, i see "Castle.Proxies.ClassNameProxy" in my datagridview.

Maybe i have to change type of some columns, but before databinding, there are no columns, after databinding is too late (i think).

There is a bit of my Map:

```
        Table("Dostawa");
        SchemaAction.All();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Nazwa).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Numer).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Material).Column("IdMaterialu");      // first referenced object
        References(x => x.Producent).Column("IdProducenta");   // second referenced object
```

Edit: With debugging i saw, that my list with is datasource contains this two objects like properties, but in this objects, only Id is known, else properties are an "threw an exception of type 'NHibernate.LazyInitializationException'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your mapping. This will eager load the Objects instead of Lazy Loading by default.

```
 References(x => x.Material).Column("IdMaterialu").Not.LazyLoad();
 References(x => x.Producent).Column("IdProducenta").Not.LazyLoad();
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. I Love simple solutions :)